# What makes a "portable app" categtorized as such?

Tags: windows, portable, portable-apps

In Windows there is a category of apps called "Portable Apps".  What makes these apps categorized as a "Portable App"?   Is it the fact that you don't need to install them to run them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A portable app is a distribution of an app that can run without requiring any installation, and should not leave any trace behind on the system after you run it, although some apps do this and they are still considered portable apps.

The idea is that you can put these on your USB stick and use them anywhere. The settings are then also stored on the USB stick, so you not only can use the app, but their settings are retained at the same location the program is being run from.

Comment: Is running without admin privileges also one of the requirements?

Comment: @Nelson In a sense, yes. Because you would only need admin privileges if you would need to modify the system.